# List index background image - to the front?

Tags: html, css

I am designing an online shop for client, and the product images need to be displayed in a frame, however this frame should be displayed over the image and not behind it (the image for the frame is a little squiggle thing and is not the same shape as the product image, hence why it needs to be on top - heres a link to a screen shot of the product page with the background images in the list - [product page](http://varoom.ie/pub_content/squiggle.png)

(Those little pink images need to be sitting on top of the images) Heres the CSS

```
.product-grid{
 list-style: none;
 margin: 0;
 color: {{ settings.grid_text_colour }};
 }

   .product-grid li{
 padding: 25px 5px 5px 5px;
 width: 190px;
 float: left;
 margin: 0 15px 10px 0;
 position: relative;
 text-align: center;
background: url({{ 'squiggle.png' | asset_url }}) no-repeat;
}
```

is there anyway that the background image (squiggle.png) which is transparent can actually sit on top of the image which is shown in the list?

any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that the product images are `<img>` tags contained inside the list items.

Since your "frame" is a background image on the parent element, it has to appear beneath any children inside that element.

There are a couple ways to get the effect you want:

1. Change the markup and CSS: add an extra element which has the frame as its background image (and change the CSS to remove the frame as background image of the list item). This element will need to be another child of the list item, and in order to appear on top of the product image it will either need to come after the image element, or it will need to have a position and a z-index.
2. Change the CSS only: set your background image on `.product-grid li:after`***, along with these other properties to make `:after` visible.

   `content: '';
   display: inline-block;`

Whether you are using an extra element or the `:after` pseudoelement to hold your frame, you'll need some additional properties to size and position it properly:

```
position: absolute;
top: -20px;
left: -20px;
right: -20px;
bottom: -20px;
```

You need to use negative values for the `top`, `left`, etc position properties to make the frame image larger than the product image. `-20px` is just an estimate; play with it and find out the correct exact value.

By doing either of these you may introduce a usability issue, so don't forget to address it with further markup changes or with JS.  If your product images are links, and the frame covers a portion of them, then the user may end up clicking on the frame when they thought they clicked the image, and wondering why they aren't getting the product page/popup/whatever.

If you go with my first suggestion above, you can fix the link issue by wrapping both the product image and the frame container element inside your link element. If you went with the second suggestion, you can either use JS to put a click handler on the entire list item which redirects to your product link, or use the link element's `:after` rather than the list item's to hold your frame image. `:before` and `:after` pseudoelements behave as children rather than siblings of the element they belong to, so a click on an anchor's `:after` element will register as a click on the anchor.

*** may be  `.product-grid li a:after` depending on how you address the link-clicking issue.

Comment: +1 for the `li:after` ideia, which can solve the problem only with CSS.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I tried both, but neither worked for me! With the first suggestion the image still remained behind, maybe my CSS was wrong. With the second the frame image no longer appears, - heres the CSS on it? .product-grid li{
  padding: 25px 5px 5px 5px;
  width: 190px;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 15px 10px 0;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
 }
.product-grid li:after {
    background: url({{ 'squiggle.png' | asset_url }}) no-repeat;
    content: ''; 
    display: inline-block;
}

Answer (score 0):

Background images are in the background, period. You will have to absolutely-position the element containing the background over an different element containing the image. You can use absolute-positioning to do this.